# Why are my CSS styles overriding my inline styles?

Tags: html, css

My `<input type=image>` inline width/height is being overridden by my `input` styles. Is there a way to correct this? Or will the inline style not work in this situation?

HTML:

```
<form id="search" name="search" form method="get" action="find_search.php">
    <input type=  "text" name=     "q" value=""  />
    <input type="hidden" name=   "cat" value=""  />
    <input type="hidden" name=  "time" value="0" />
    <input type="hidden" name="letter" value=""  />
    <input type="hidden" name="offset" value="0" />
    <input type="hidden" name=  "type" value="quick" />
    <input type= "image" src="images/search_button.png" value="Search" width="200" height="50" />
</form>
```

CSS:

```
input {
   width:50%;
   padding:0px;
   outline:none;
   height:36px;
   font-size:24px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this by using more specific CSS selectors like `input[type=text]` and `input[type=image]`. So if you want the height/width specified in your question to only apply to `<input type="text">`, you would do something like this:

Keep the non-height/width properties in the less specific `input` selector:

```
input {
   padding:0px;
   outline:none;
   font-size:24px;
}
```

Then use the height/width properties in the `input[type=text]` selector:

```
input[type=text] {
   width:50%;
   height:36px;
}
```

Then you can add a differnet height/width for the `input[type=image]` selector:

```
input[type=image] {
   width: 200px;
   height: 50px;
}
```

Also, keep in mind that you can make your selectors more specific if you use the `id` of the `form` in your selectors, like so:

- `#search input`
- `#search input[type=text]`
- `#search input[type=image]`

Comment: This selector will catch all of the *texty* type input fields:  `input[type="text"], input[type="password"], input[type="search"], input[type="email"], input[type="tel"], input[type="url"]`.  This selector will catch all of the *button* type input elements:  `input[type="submit"], input[type="reset"], input[type="button"], button`

Comment: @user2088368 No problem! Don't forget to mark the answer as "accepted" if it solved your issue. It's the check mark below the upvote/downvote arrows.

Answer (score 0):

I personally would use classes such as:

```
    <form id="search" name="search" form method="get" action="find_search.php">

    <input class="input" type=  "text" name=     "q" value=""  />
    <input type="hidden" name=   "cat" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name=  "time" value="0" />
    <input type="hidden" name="letter" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="offset" value="0" />
    <input type="hidden" name=  "type" value="quick" />
    <input class="button" type="image" src="images/search_button.png"  value="Search"  width="200" height="50"
  />

  </form>

.input
{
   width:50%;
   padding:0px;
   outline:none;
   height:36px;
   font-size:24px;
}
.button{
   /*your button CSS*/
}
```